# MySQL using variables in SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use variables in SELECT without SET before it?

Somehow '@period' variable not always works properly. For example in MySQL Workbench (v5.2), the result is showed only after 2nd invocation, if the variable is changed the result will be correct only on 2nd run. phpMyAdmin shows correct rows count but no entries, can someone explain please what is wrong in using variables in such a way:

```
    select sql_no_cache @num := @num + 1 as `#`, l.* from (

    select s.* from (
    select
    @num := 0 as 'Label 1',
    @period := 31 as 'LAbel 2',
    '' as 'Label 3'

    union

    select concat(users.first_name, ' ',users.last_name),u.type, u.date, u.description from (

    select c.user_id as uguid, 'type1' as type, c.date_start as date, c.description from table1 c 
    where deleted = 0
    and date_start > SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,@period)

    union
    ...
) as u) as l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a mistake.
The reason is that the variable is used before it's definition. '@period' is defined in the query, but it's first usage occures in the subquery that's executes first.
So the solution is to put variable definition on the same level with the subquery where it used.

Something like:

```
    select sql_no_cache @num := @num + 1 as `#`, l.* from (

        select s.* from (
        select
        @num := 0 as 'Label 1',
        '' as 'LAbel 2',
        '' as 'Label 3'

        union

        select concat(users.first_name, ' ',users.last_name),u.type, u.date, u.description from     (
            select o2.* from
             (select @period:=31) as o1
             join (
               select c.user_id as uguid, 'type1' as type, c.date_start as date, c.description from table1 c 
               where deleted = 0
                 and date_start > SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,@period)

              union
                ...
             ) as o2
       ) as u
   ) as l
```